# How to show hashmap values in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, hashmap, uirepeat

I have bean "MyBean", which has property HashMap - "map" which values type is MyClass. I want to show some properties of map in jsf using ui:repeat.
But these code:

```
<ui:repeat  var="var"  value="#{mybean.map}" >
<tr> 
<td> <h:outputText value="#{var.value.property1}"></h:outputText> </td>
<td><h:outputText value="#{var.value.property2}"></h:outputText></td>
</tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

But this code didn't show anything. Though when I try to show hashmap values in jsp this way, it was succesfull. Where I am wrong? And how fix that?

Comment: (@Aram: you need to put an empty line between normal text and code blocks, otherwise it doesn't format properly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) for the `repeat` value attribute:

> The name of a collection of items that this tag iterates over. The collection may be a `List`, array, `java.sql.ResultSet`, or an individual java `Object`. If the collection is null, this tag does nothing.

So, var is set as your `HashMap` and EL tries to look up the key `"value"` on it. You will need to expose your entry set as a `List`.

Comment: @Aram Gevorgyan - like `dataTable`, `repeat` is an index-based component (see the _offset_ and _size_ attributes). Adam Winer (who was in the JSF expert group) discusses a similar case here: [Using Sets with UIData](http://sfjsf.blogspot.com/2006/03/usings-sets-with-uidata.html).

Answer (score 26):

That's indeed a major pita. The `<c:forEach>` supported `Map` for long. Apart from supplying another getter as suggested by McDowell, you could also workaround this by a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174).

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{util:toList(bean.map)}" var="entry">
    #{entry.key} = #{entry.value} <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

where the EL function look like this

```java
public static List<Map.Entry<?, ?>> toList(Map<?, ?> map) {
    return = map != null ? new ArrayList<Map.Entry<?,?>>(map.entrySet()) : null;
}
```

---

Or, if you're on EL 2.2 already (provided by Servlet 3.0 compatible containers such as Glassfish 3, Tomcat 7, etc), then just use `Map#entrySet()` and then `Set#toArray()`.

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.map.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
    #{entry.key} = #{entry.value} <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, your syntax `#{util:toList(bean.map)}`, is `util` a managed bean, BalusC? I never see this syntax before.

Comment: @Thang: it's an EL function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174 It's like as JSTL functions. [OmniFaces](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/vdldoc/index.html) has also  some in `of` namespace, see `of:mapToList()`.