# dynamic number of selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I've two pieces of code, one that work and one that doesn't. I'm accessing accessing different objects in from a list in different `selectOneMenu`. So if my list is of size 4 then I have 4 `selectOneMenu`. There is a `spinner` above the `selectOneMenu` 's to notify how many of them I want.
 I don't understand why the first one using `varstatus` to access a list works and the second one which use the var doesn't. A `Map` is a custom entity btw.

**Works :**

```
<p:spinner value="#{matchCreation.numbreOfmaps}" min="1" max="7">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="mapsGroup" execute="mapsGroup"/>
</p:spinner>
<!-- maps start  -->
<h:panelGroup id="mapsGroup">
    <table>
        <ui:repeat var="mapPlayed" value="#{matchCreation.playedMaps}" varStatus="status">
            <tr><td>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{matchCreation.playedMaps[status.index]}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{matchCreation.mapList}" var="map" itemValue="#{map}" itemLabel="#{map.name}"/>
                    <f:converter binding="#{mapConverter}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td></tr>  
        </ui:repeat> 
    </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Does NOT work :**

```
<p:spinner value="#{matchCreation.numbreOfmaps}" min="1" max="7">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="mapsGroup" execute="mapsGroup"/>
</p:spinner>
<!-- maps start  -->
<h:panelGroup id="mapsGroup">
    <table>
        <ui:repeat var="mapPlayed" value="#{matchCreation.playedMaps}">
            <tr><td>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{mapPlayed}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{matchCreation.mapList}" var="map" itemValue="#{map}" itemLabel="#{map.name}"/>
                    <f:converter binding="#{mapConverter}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td></tr>  
        </ui:repeat> 
    </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In this one the list will contain the number of map specified but they will all be equal to `mapList.get(0)`.

**java:**

```
private List<Map> mapList; // initiated in post construct.
private List<Map> playedMaps;
private int numbreOfmaps = 1;

public List<Map> getPlayedMaps() {
    // I know this is not advised but I didn't really think of another way.
    // It's not heavy work anyway.
    while (playedMaps.size() > numbreOfmaps) {
        playedMaps.remove(playedMaps.size() - 1);
    }
    while (playedMaps.size() < numbreOfmaps) {
        playedMaps.add(mapList.get(0));
    }
    return playedMaps;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show hashmap values in jsf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001743/how-to-show-hashmap-values-in-jsf)

Comment: @lametaweb check the java code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ui:repeat var="mapPlayed">` represents a scoped variable, not a bean property. To imagine the "under the covers" working, it look like:

```
for (Map mapPlayed : matchCreation.getPlayedMaps()) {
    // ...
    System.out.println(mapPlayed);
}
```

When using `<p:selectOneMenu value="#{mapPlayed}">`, JSF actually sets the  submitted value in the scoped variable, not the bean property. Under the covers, imagine it like:

```
for (Map mapPlayed : matchCreation.getPlayedMaps()) {
    Map newMapPlayed = getSubmittedValueSomehow();
    mapPlayed = newMapPlayed;
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't get reflected in the list.

With the loop index it works better:

```
for (int index = 0; index < matchCreation.getPlayedMaps().size(); index++) 
    Map newMapPlayed = getSubmittedValueSomehow();
    matchCreation.getPlayedMaps().set(index, newMapPlayed);
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, shadowing names of standard Java SE API classes like `Map` (from `java.util.Map`) is a terribly bad idea.

Comment: The last piece of code you posted works? Because I cannot make that work. Because add(index, object) adds the object but all other subsequent indexes are incremented. So with a base list of size 3, after using add(i,o) the list size is 4. Iterating over it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sens.

Comment: For the var loop: It makes zero sens and this line is redundant `mapPlayed = newMapPlayed;`. Why would they do that ?!

Comment: They didn't. You did. That's why it didn't work. I just translated your attempt into understandable Java code so you can see that it indeed doesn't make sense.